# ASP.NET World Map - Region Controlling

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, dictionary, controls

I am trying to make a page showing the world map as image. But then I also want to add controls to the image itself, when a specific country is selected.

How do I add controls above the image? As you know, the countries, have specific boundaries. And an image is only a bunch of pixels, how do I define each country and how to add the specific control for mouse?

I have no clues..

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: It's not related to ASP.NET that much. Try using one of the famous graphic editing software for creating an Image Map. Here is how to do that: http://tinyurl.com/image-map-how-to

Comment: I think ASP.NET ImageMap control will do the job, but I don't know if it can include child controls in easy way

Comment: Hey @Saito, but I want to create custom shame regions.. not the rectangle-like ones from ASP.NET ImageMap.. is it possible to do ImageMaps with custom shapes on ASP.NET ? Thanks ;)

Comment: @DarkLink The ASP.NET [ImageMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295596(v=expression.40).aspx) control has a Polygonal Hotspot tool.

Comment: How do I use that Polygonal Hotspot tool ? Is there any tutorial ? thanks